# Mail sent in localhost and website created from iis7,but not in website created from iis6

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, localhost, mail-server

I am working on an eCommerce site using *nopcommerce*.  I wanted to send an email if the user has already registered and is trying to register again with the same email login.  I have written the code for sending the email and for showing the message "The mail has been successfully sent".  It's working fine locally and on a website in IIS7 but it is not working on a website in IIS6.

Can anyone suggest a solution?